# exclusiveMaximum annotation miss-added in api documentation Swagger

Tags: java, eclipse, swagger, swagger-2.0

I'm documenting an api, but some code is being added when loading in swagger web.
I'm writing my api in Eclipse with propper annotations for swagger, for example:

```
@ApiModelProperty(value = "Account number", example = "3507898", position = 3)
@Min(17)
@Max(9999999)
@NotNull
private Integer accountNumber;
```

But when running my java app in eclipse and loading documentation in swagger, it shows:

```
accountNumber   integer($int32)
example: 3507898
minimum: 17
maximum: 9999999
exclusiveMinimum: false
exclusiveMaximum: false
Account number
```

where is that exclusiveMinimum/exclusiveMaximum coming from??? why is it generated by itself? is it mandatory to use exclusiveMinimum/exclusiveMaximum when using min and max values?

Hope someone can help out.
thanks

Alejo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To exclude the boundary values, 
specify 
`exclusiveMinimum: true` and `exclusiveMaximum: true`
for the above piece of code it says that `accountNumber` can have values from `17` to `9999999`.

Though its not a mandatory attribute and have came with `@Min` and `@Max` by default, the minimum and maximum values are included in the range i.e. 
`exclusiveMinimum: false` and `exclusiveMaximum: false`

I hope this answer your question

Comment: Thank you.But is there a way not to show them since i'm not using the annotations, just using max and min.